# ローカルで動くチャット機能が本番環境で動作しない

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

**実現したいこと**
本番環境で動かないチャットアプリを動作するよう設定したい
改善するために必要な要素を特定したい

**実行環境**
Rails 5.2.4.2
nginx 1.12.2
unicorn 5.4.1
AmazonLinux2

**エラー**
デベロッパーツールのコンソール

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://ドメイン/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

log/production.log

```
Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: close, HTTP_UPGRADE: )
```

現在試したこと
config/environments/prodution.rbの

１．`config.action_cable.allowed_request_origin = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]`を有効にしドメインを設定

**ご教示頂きたい点**
他に必要な要素を教えていただきたい

必要となりそうな要素を一通り検索した結果下記の３点が目にとまりましたが、使用しているものもあれば使用していないものもあり取捨選択が困難でした

・AWSのELB設定 （HTTP/HTTPSでのWebSockets通信はサポートしていない?)
・/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf で cable を設定
・redisの設定

ご教示頂けますと幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問文から読み取るに AWS をご利用のようですが、であれば現状の構成が分からないと何とも言えない……気がします。[edit] して情報を追加してみていただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答が遅くなり大変申し訳ございません。失念してしまっておりました。

https://teratail.com/questions/231471
上記の内容をもとに解決することができました。

ご回答頂き誠にありがとうございました！

Comment: 他で解決したということであれば、回答の要点を書きつつ[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)することもできます。少し待てば自分で自分の回答を承認することもできますので、お試しください。

Comment: 承知いたしました。
時間がたったにも関わらず、ご返信までいただきありがとうございました！

Answer (score 3):

https://teratail.com/questions/231471

上記の内容をもとに自己解決できました。

・「config/environments/prodution.rbファイルでドメインを有効化」以外に行ったこと

nginx ***.conf に下記のコードを追加しました。

```
location /cable {
            proxy_pass http://アプリケーションサーバー/cable;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
            proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```